# HTML5 resumable and chunked upload of large files (> 500MB)

Tags: jquery, html, upload

Is it possible to implement resumable and slice (chunked) upload for large sizefiles (>500MB) using HTML5 (BLOB API)?

I tried to use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.
In documentation its said that is supports:
Resumable uploads:
Aborted uploads can be resumed with browsers supporting the Blob API.
Chunked uploads:
Large files can be uploaded in smaller chunks with browsers supporting the Blob API.

But it seems that it tries to load file in RAM and that even hangs my system.  Did anyone come across such problem what were the solutions? Maybe HTML5 is inappropriate here?

Comment: i have the same issue i tried plupload, dropzone, fineuploader all are failed browser goning to be un responsive or worst it gonna be crushed.
Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I've used dropzone to successfully upload several GB files. As far as resumable, I haven't tried that out.

Comment: @Sully how were you able to use dropzone wih GB large files? It does not support chunked file upload and if you use PHP backend then this is almost impossible... at list with shared hosting servers.

Comment: I used the "ASP.Net" option (which still requires some config tweaking to support it). No experience using Dropzone with PHP, so yea I can't help with that.

Answer (score 19):

Try one of these:

- [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)
- [fineuploader](http://fineuploader.com/)
- [resumable](https://github.com/23/resumable.js)

I think they all support chunking/slicing, and at least several of them support resuming. At least plupload and fineuploader have jQuery plugins.

Comment: Note that Resumable is the only free (Non GPL at least).