# Efficiently encrypt/decrypt large file with cryptojs

Tags: encryption, browser, large-files, cryptojs

I want to encrypt large string (200 MB).
The string come from dataUrl (base64) corresponding to file.

I'm doing my encryption in the browser.

My issue is that at the moment, i chunked string into small part into an array.
Then i encrypt this chunks.

At the moment encrypting the string will full the memory.
Here is how i'm doing it.

```
var encryptChunk = function(chunk, index){
  encryptedChunks.push( aesEncryptor.process( chunk ));
  sendUpdateMessage( "encryption", index+1, numberOfChunks );
}
chunkedString.forEach(encryptChunk);
encryptedChunks.push( aesEncryptor.finalize() );
```

I assume that, there should be a better way of doing this. But i can't find a memroy efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing something similar to you. To directly answer your question of "is there a more memory efficient way?" .. well I use a web worker for processing progressive ciphering which seems to work.

```
  //pass in what you need here
  var worker = new Worker("path/to/worker.js");

  worker.postMessage({
                key: getKeyAndIvSomehow(),
                file: file,
                chunkSize: MY_CHUNK_SIZE
            });

  worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
               // create the blob from e.data.encrypted
            });
```

You will need to import the cryptoJS script into your worker: `importScripts('cryptoJS.all.min.js')`

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with the encrypted chunks? If you're, say, uploading them over the network, you don't need to store them in an array first.  Instead, you can upload the encrypted file chunk by chunk, either writing your own chunked upload implementation (it's not terribly hard) or by [using an existing library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683263/html5-resumable-and-chunked-upload-of-large-files-500mb)

Ditto for the input: you can encrypt it as you read it.  You can use the [JS File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) to read the file in chunks, using the [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) method.

Other than that, your code looks just like the recommended way to [progressively encrypt](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Progressive_Ciphering) a file.

Comment: I do send it over the network.
For the moment, i build the array, then pass the array to the Blob constructor. Then add the blob in a FormData object.

How would you propose to proceed?

Comment: That's what i ended up doing, and it work pretty well.
In my case, i was able to send 2go files. I ended up having issue on the opening, but that's not related to the problem in question here.