# Upload large files on the website

Tags: php, web-services, file-upload, upload

On my own website I need a feature which allows users to upload large files up to 5 Gb. The possible way is to increase upload_max_filesize option in php.ini. But I dont think it is good solution.
Another way is to upload file in chunks. Would that work smoothly?

What is the best solution ? Or maybe I should use some 3rd party services?

Thanks!

Comment: Provide FTP access, or setup 1 domain where you allow 5GB upload_max_filesize but with increased security level

Answer (score 1):

You should use an upload form with eg. ajax or maybe something ready made with html5 or flash (who uses flash anymore?). There are ready made solutions what also chunk the upload data.

Chunking coupled with upload resuming is the better solution.

Also check this question on stackoverflow here: [html5-resumable-and-chunked-upload-of-large-files-500mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683263/html5-resumable-and-chunked-upload-of-large-files-500mb)

The first answer there gives some ready made solution links.