# Ajax With Multiple File Upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, image-uploading

I'm making a gallery system where you are multiple photos - everything is work very fine but when internet is slow (2 min uploading time -_-) the entered data returns empty..
I'm using malsup's jquery form plugin for helping ajax upload.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: how can i verify the entered title, description and data and then upload my photos (i made it but in slow internet this isn't working)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

the bigger problem here is, that your plugin does seem to be limited by your max_execution_time php.ini setting, which kills php scripts running longer than a specified time, in this case after 2 minutes. you need a plugin that handles chunked file uploads, and blueimp is the usual way to go here.

your second question, to verify the data, can be handled by javascript (jquery) before you send it and/or by php after you received the data.

i always use blueimp (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for multiple file uploads, it works well even beyond the servers script execution time limit.

Comment: but my problem is that i need to add title to my gallery, description and tags and verify these datas and then upload the photos.

Comment: but the bigger problem here is, that your plugin does seem to be limited by your max_execution_time php.ini setting, which kills php scripts running longer than a specified time, in this case after 2 minutes. you need a plugin that handles chunked file uploads, and blueimp is the usual way to go here. your second question, to verify the data, can be handled by javascript (jquery) before you send it and/or by php after you received the data.

Comment: well but if i use this plugin user will upload photos before submit the user's data

Comment: no, you can start the upload after you checked the users data. usually these things get stored in a database, so you can check the user data after the upload and then save it in the database along with the image path. i dont know about your code, though..

Comment: but if i upload the the photos before verify data from form when there is a problem with form's data the photos will already uploaded

Comment: blueimp has a "start upload"-button. you can easily add your own function to it with jquery to check the user data first.

Comment: you should know that chunked file uploads is the only option to upload large files, that take longer than max_execution_time. you can try http://www.plupload.com/, http://fineuploader.com/ or https://github.com/23/resumable.js, if you dont like blueimp. see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683263/html5-resumable-and-chunked-upload-of-large-files-500mb I dont know if they support multiple file uploads, though.